# Inserting a null value into the database

Tags: sql

Good Morning,

Say I have an insert statement:

```
Insert INTO tblTest (fieldOne,FieldTwo,fieldThree) VALUES ('valueOne','valueTwo','null')
```

This statement doesn't seem to want to insert a null value into the database... I have also tried to insert the word "nothing".

Has anyone any ideas how to make this work? I am using SQL server 2005.

Comment: You want to insert 'NULL' string or NULL?

Comment: next time pls show us the table(create script or something), it may be possible that fieldThree is an Number, then you cant enter strings btw hgulyan should wourk too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert INTO tblTest (fieldOne,FieldTwo) VALUES ('valueOne','valueTwo').
```

Comment: Be careful with this one J Harley - it's possible you could have a default value being applied by the database if it has a default constraint. If you really want null (and have a default constraint), this won't work.

Comment: However, if you don't explicitly need a null in there - you're just not able to specifiy a value at the time - then this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, instead of 'null', try null (lose the quotes)

Then check that the fieldThree column on TblTest doesn't have any constraint prohibiting the use of null values...

Comment: +1, when you put quotes around the NULL you create a literal char(4) string of the word 'NULL' and not the undefined value NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Insert INTO tblTest (fieldOne,FieldTwo,fieldThree) VALUES ('valueOne','valueTwo',NULL)
```

Check for *fieldThree* not to be **NOT NULL**.

If you're trying to **INSERT** *'NULL'* string, then just check if *fieldThree* is **varchar** type.